# Looking for a French translation for "ornament"

Tags: traduction, anglais

Title says it all. Like a christmas tree ornament, what would you call it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

“*Décorations*“, “*Décorations de Noël*” are the words we use about christmas tree ornament.

and as [Joubarc](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/102/joubarc) stated in his commentary:

> [...] it's not limited to Christmas either. Note the singular is décoration; ornement also exists but isn't used much nowadays and mostly for immobile stuff (statues in a park, for example).

Comment: And it's not limited to Christmas either. Note the singular is [décoration](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9coration); [ornement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ornement) also exists but isn't used much nowadays and mostly for immobile stuff (statues in a park, for example).